# Cannot find module 'connect' in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

when I try to run `node app.js` I get this error :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
   ...
```

I added connect to my `package.json` file, and when I run `npm update` , it seems to do something, but actually it doesn't, I dont know what to do , I just runed `npm install express` , and I still get that error.
any help?

app.js :

```
var connect = require('connect');
var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8080);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

// rooms which are currently available in chat
var rooms = ['room1','room2','room3'];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username){
        // store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // store the room name in the socket session for this client
        socket.room = 'room1';
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // send client to room 1
        socket.join('room1');
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to room1');
        // echo to room 1 that a person has connected to their room
        socket.broadcast.to('room1').emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected to this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, 'room1');
    });

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    socket.on('switchRoom', function(newroom){
        // leave the current room (stored in session)
        socket.leave(socket.room);
        // join new room, received as function parameter
        socket.join(newroom);
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected to '+ newroom);
        // sent message to OLD room
        socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has left this room');
        // update socket session room title
        socket.room = newroom;
        socket.broadcast.to(newroom).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username+' has joined this room');
        socket.emit('updaterooms', rooms, newroom);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
});
```

and my package.json :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.0",
    "socket.io": "*",
    "connect": "*",
    "underscore": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `var connect = require('connect');`?

Comment: check `/node_modules/` directory to see if it's there.  If not, try `npm install`.  If not try removing connect from the package.json and run `npm install connect --save`

Comment: Could you post your `package.json` contents, npm output, and `app.js` contents? That'll help identify your issue.

Comment: I just added those files contents @Jondlm

Comment: Try running `npm install` instead of `npm update`. Does it give you any errors?

Comment: try `npm link` to install all from your package json

Comment: Another thought -- consider using express-io [http://express-io.org] -- getting connect and sockets seems like a means to an end, and express.io may be perfect for this app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `npm update` gets newer versions of modules that are already installed. As @jondlm and @user645715 suggest, use `npm install` or `npm install -d` to tell NPM to go through your `package.json` and any child `package.json` in subfolders, installing any missing dependencies into `./node_modules/`. Or use `sudo npm install --global connect` to install `connect` to a global module folder where it will be available for future projects.

Comment: I did all that, but it stops somewhere in installing, I dont know what to do . even what to ask :(

Comment: Can you show the console trace?  Does it fail when you run `npm install` or is that successful, and it fails when you run node.app?  Another option is to delete the `node_modules` directory and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this 
sudo npm install -g connect

it installs connect in the directory folder where you are working,but if u want to link it to the root folder just type.

sudo npm link connect

if still the error come then ping me please.:)